# Can PHP echo text with same formating as copy pasted?

Tags: php, echo

I want to make program that will echo the same text message as user copy pasted (as code)

example:

```html
echo 'text
         text
            text
         text
      text';
      
      
      OUTPUT: text text text text text
      
      WHAT I WANT: 
      
      text
         text
            text
         text
      text
```

Comment: Use a [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag.

Comment: Yes! This did the trick! Thank you!!! <3